# Using JSDoc on ECMAScript with extended syntax

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

Can anyone tell me if it's possible to use JSDoc on JavaScript (more like ECMAScript) with some additional features? For example, I have code like this:

```
function(a : String, b : Number) : Object {
    // do some stuff here
}
```

As you can see it's almost JavaScript but with possibility to specify type of arguments and return value. So can I somehow use JSDoc on this syntax? Is there any method to write some kind of plugin for it?

Thanks.

Comment: What you have looks an awful lot like Typescript, which already supports JSDoc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I was on my phone earlier, I can answer in a bit more detail now.

To start, I think you're confusing JSDoc with its implementations. JSDoc is just a standard way for people to document Javascript code. In and of itself, it isn't a program and it doesn't do anything. Now, there are certain programs that are aware of JSDoc and provide certain features based on it. For example, an IDE might show JSDoc when hovering over a method. So if you wanted to, you could use JSDoc anywhere you wanted, including in code for different languages. However, if you wanted programs that take advantage of JSDoc to recognize it, you have a bit of a problem.

I highly doubt any current JSDoc programs are going to recognize the format in any language except strict Javascript. I downloaded jsdoc-toolkit and it's definitely true of that one, and probably true for most of them. If you really want JSDoc for that code, you'll probably have to write some kind of program (or edit one) yourself. Unless this superset of ECMAScript is a common language, in which case there might be a program out there.